# Find "real" formula for a formula group

Tags: regex, excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to find the "real" formula of a group. For example, these are the formulas

```
=If(A$4>$A1,"Long","Short") 
=If(B$4>$A1,"Long","Short") 
=If(A$4>$A2,"Long","Short")
=If(A$4>$A$2,"Long","Short)
```

The forth formula is a different one. The first 3 formulas should be the same formula that is a cell fixed 4th row compare to a cell fixed at column A. The result should show 2 "real" formula. Something like this

```
=If($4>$A,"Long","Short")
=If($4>$A$2,"Long","Short")
```

How do I design a regex (or any other method) in VBA to extract that "real" formula from the "nominal" formulas?

Comment: Count the number of `$`

Comment: @Mikku I don't think that would work at all. `$A4>C5` is different from `$B4>C5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your formulas to display in R1C1 format by using File,Options,Formulas and ticking R1C1 style. In such a style your four example formulas would display (If they were entered in column 3) as

```
=IF(R4C[-2]>RC1,"Long","Short")
=IF(R4C[-1]>R[-1]C1,"Long","Short")
=IF(R4C[-2]>R[-1]C1,"Long","Short")
=IF(R4C[-2]>R2C1,"Long","Short")
```

The fixed portions of the addresses don't have braces [] so if you remove the braces and their contents you get

```
R4C>RC1
R4C>RC1
R4C>RC1
R4C>R2C1
```

and no 4 is different from the others

Comment: This is so much simpler than Regex. Thanks you very much.